# Did technology evolve in the 20 years humanity left Earth to Godzilla?

Tags: godzilla-kaijuu-wakusei

Humanity left Earth to escape Godzilla.  In their relativity, they only spent 20 years away from the planet, while the planet didn't see them for ~20,000 years.

When they return to fight Godzilla (not a spoiler), you see large landing ships, hoverbikes, powered suits, and many other pieces of high technology.  Their legged tanks are even strong enough for Godzilla to feel threatened by.

Did the technology of the people who left advance that far in the 20 years they were gone?  Or did the other 2 alien species impart their technology to the survivors?

Comment: I'd say that rather than advancing, the three races used those 20 years to better integrate their technologies. So they did not advance as much as combined their exisiting tech in making new machines and ships (yeah, that can be called advancing). Plus that they had limited resurces, so maybe they were limited in the number of prototypes they could build (they could harvest resources from asteroids like in Knights of Sidonia, but it's not shown). I'd say that they 'refined' their tech, rather than 'advance' by a high margin, though it appears 'improved'.

Comment: I would speculate they had those all those ships and weapons from the moment they left. They are clearly running out of suplies, so I find it hard to believe they are able to gain new along the way by ways of mining. The one thing that changes was strategy. When they were leaving, they had no idea about Godzilla's shield. They could easily have all those high-tech weapons and still not hurt Godzilla before they left. But after learning about it's shield, they could properly use all they had left.